# \ForEach fails with underscores

Tags: loops, for-loop

For the automatic generation of reports I'm using the `\ForEach` loop of the `forarray` package.
This is just great as it saves me lots of time.

However, there is one issue: When the items I iterate through contain underscores I get lots of errors (even though LaTeX finishes compiling and creates the PDF).

Here's a minimum (not) working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{forarray}

\begin{document}
\ForEach
{,}
{
    \section{\thislevelitem}
    This section covers the topic of \thislevelitem.
} {test_one, test_two, test_three}
\end{document}
```

In case I replace the underscores with dashes all works fine.

Is there a way to deal with these underscores in the `\ForEach` loop?

**Edit to be more specific**:
While using `test_\one`, etc. would work in the above minimal example it does not for my purpose because I usually use `\thislevelitem` to access figures (including underscores in their path).
In case it is possible to replace `\_` by `_` in `\thislevelitem` fore generating the figure path it would be a solution.

Comment: Underscores are used in `math mode`. When you are not in math mode, `LaTeX` complains.

Comment: Indeed the only problem in the MWE (besides the spurious brace in `test_one},`) is that you are not in math mode when you print the text `test_one`, `test_two` etc. LaTeX treats `_` as a marker for subscripts in math mode, so `_` requires math mode. If I say `\section{$\thislevelitem$} This section covers the topic of $\thislevelitem$.` to get into math mode there is no error, but of course the output is math-y.

Comment: `test\_one` and so on

Comment: test\_one would work in my minimum working example, however I normally use \thislevelitem to include figures (which filenames including underscores).
Using test\_one would then not allow me to access to my figures anymore. except if there's a way of replacing the "\_" with "_" before accessing to these figures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within file-names you can use `\string` for turning special input-characters like `_` into ordinary ones.

Be aware that LaTeX' Computer Modern Roman Font in the pdf-output-file doesn't deliver an underscore but a diacritic dot for the underscore-input-character.

In order to get in the output the underscore-character for the underscore-input-character, you need to switch, e.g., to Computer Modern Typewriter (cmr):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{forarray}

\begin{document}

\ForEach{,}%
        {%
          \section{\texttt{\thislevelitem}}%
          This section covers the topic of \texttt{\thislevelitem}.%
        }% 
        {%
          test\string_one, test\string_two, test\string_three%
        }%

\end{document}
```

By the way: With `\input` (La)TeX will keep expanding tokens while gathering the filename. Thus you can, e.g., implement an `\if..`-switch and a macro which either delivers `\textunderscore` or delivers `\string_` depending on whether the thing is to be printed in the text or to be used within the system as part of a file-name:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{test_one.tex}
This is test\textunderscore one
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{test_two.tex}
This is test\textunderscore two
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{test_three.tex}
This is test\textunderscore three
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{forarray}

\newif\iffilename
\global\filenamefalse
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myunderscore{%
  \iffilename
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi{\string_}{\textunderscore}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ForEach{,}%
        {%
          \section{\thislevelitem}%
          This section covers the topic of \thislevelitem.%
          {% open up a local scope.
            \filenametrue
            \\This is the file-name with underscores: \texttt{\thislevelitem}%
            \filenamefalse
            \\This is the content of the file \textbf{\thislevelitem.tex}:
            \filenametrue
            \input{\thislevelitem.tex}%
          }% close the local scope.
        }% 
        {%
          % Be aware that \ForEach does remove leading spaces but does not remove
          % trailing spaces from comma-separated items and therefore the last item
          % must be trailed by a comment-char neutralizing the space which comes 
          % into being due to \endlinechar:
          test\myunderscore one, test\myunderscore two, test\myunderscore three%<-This comment must be!!!
        }%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Even more general you can implement a macro which does select arguments depending on its current definition:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{test_one.tex}
This is test\textunderscore one
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{test_two.tex}
This is test\textunderscore two
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{test_three.tex}
This is test\textunderscore three
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{forarray}

\newcommand\SelectMyThingie[3]{#3}%
\newcommand\printdigits{\renewcommand\SelectMyThingie[3]{##3}}%
\newcommand\printtextphrases{\renewcommand\SelectMyThingie[3]{##2}}%
\newcommand\createfilenames{\renewcommand\SelectMyThingie[3]{##1}}%

\begin{document}

\ForEach{,}%
        {%
          {% open up a local scope:
            \printdigits
            \section{\thislevelitem}%
            This section covers the topic of \thislevelitem.\\
            \printtextphrases
            This is the content of the file \textbf{\thislevelitem.tex}:
            \createfilenames
            \input{\thislevelitem.tex}%
          }% close the local scope.
        }% 
        {%
          % Be aware that \ForEach does remove leading spaces but does not remove
          % trailing spaces from comma-separated items and therefore the last item
          % must be trailed by a comment-char neutralizing the space which comes 
          % into being due to \endlinechar:
          test\SelectMyThingie{\string_one}{\textunderscore one}{~1}, 
          test\SelectMyThingie{\string_two}{\textunderscore two}{~2},
          test\SelectMyThingie{\string_three}{\textunderscore three}{~3}%<-this comment must be!
        }%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: **THANKS A LOT**. That perfectly does the job!

Comment: using the first solution `test\string_one`, etc. in combination with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` works like a charm without any other modifications.